# Outbound HTTPS connection used as inbound control channel

Tags: web-development

I have an application which is configured through a web management interface accessed from the same network as the application is running on. I've been asked to make it manageable from the cloud using an HTTPS outbound connection (the customer in mind is doing MITM decryption on their web firewall and wants to sniff the traffic).

Is there an established convention on how this is generally achieved? There would need to be a separate application running on a cloud server listening for connections, but once the connection is made - then what? Is it possible to make a Websocket connection to the external cloud service and use that to communicate with the existing management API on the firewalled app - effectively proxying everything through the application in the cloud?

Comment: It's not quite clear what business purpose this detour over the “cloud” would achieve. Is the cloud only being used here because of the buzzwords? Or is purely internal communication with the management dashboard unacceptable because of policies requiring *everything* to go through the firewall? In that case, there might be simpler approaches to route the traffic through the firewall than bouncing traffic off an external server. If the firewall will only accept outgoing HTTP requests it is *possible* to connect two internal computers, but it would be slow and require costly custom development.

Comment: My best guess is that they want to be able to offer a managed service monitoring this product on many different customers' networks without needing VPNs into each.

Comment: Then it might be good to clarify the actual requirements/needs. This sounds like the kind of problem where a 30-minute chat with a stakeholder can save a few person-months of development effort. I have a feeling the appropriate solution is either going to be “host the entire management API in the cloud, which the application polls regularly for instructions, possibly using WebSockets for real-time updates” or “tunnel a VPN protocol over HTTP(S) until this triggers intrusion detection rules”.